# How to delete a script button in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I have a drawing object that has an makro assigned to it. How can I delete the "button" if it's no longer needed? Left click runs the macro, right click has no effect to it...

Answer (score 3):

A right-click should enable a menu on the button.

[image: Screenshots]

If you are not getting this behavior, it could be a compatibility issue with your browser. Ensure you're using a [browser that's compatible with Google Docs](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375082?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

On my PC I could not delete a drawing from a Google spreadsheet. I opened it on my Android phone's sheets app and clicking the drawing brought up a delete option, which worked.